# I get ArgumentException String is not a valid semantic version when installing npm packages from the quickstart guide

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I didn't do anything special just copied the package.json from the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure) and tried to run npm install.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.8.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code E500

npm ERR! ArgumentException String is not a valid semantic version.: npm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\angular2\hello-world\npm-debug.log
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong npm registry. It can be set globally or in each project using  .npmrc.
It should be `registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/`